# Android project structure based on features

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently using the default android folder structure. It's now becoming very hard to manage the activities and views. I was wonder if there way to structure my project layouts and activities by features.

For example:

Following is my current project structure.

```
Java
  -Activity
    OrderListActivity.java
    ProductListAcitvity.java
Res
  -Layout
    OrderListView.xml
    ProductView.xml
```

I am trying to find a way to combine the view and activities into a same folder like:

```
 Java
  -Features
    -OrderList
        OrderListActivity.java
        OrderListView.xml
    -Products
        ProductListActivity.java
        ProductView.xml
```

Is this structure possible with gradle? if so could you please provide some samples gradle settings to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a java source file with layout file in the same directory. But you can organize each layout by features with a slight hack in your app `build.gradle`.

First, create a root directory for the layouts in res directory. The name should be `layouts`:

```
res/layouts
```

Then, you can create a directory for the layout based on the features. We use `OrderList` and `Products`. Each directory needs a layout directory inside of them. Now create the directories in the `layouts` like this:

```
res/layouts/orderlist/layout
res/layouts/products/layout
```

Then, add the following code to your app build.gradle:

```
android {

     ...

      sourceSets {
        main {
          res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res',
                         'src/main/res/layouts',
                         'src/main/res/layouts/orderlist',
                         'src/main/res/layouts/products',
        }
      }

   ...

}
```

Change your project to project view like this:

[image]

Sync your project to update the build.gradle. Now, you can add your layout inside the `orderlist` and `products`

Answer (score 0):

In short, not possible.

If your app contains a large amount of files, you can separate them into different modules.

Comment: ok i can separate the java classes in modules. What about layout files? i don't want all xml files in 1 folder.

Comment: I am not talking about packages. I am talking about module. In Android studio you can create new module from the new menu.You can keep different xml files in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have java files with xml resources inside the same folder.  They belong to different categories.  What you could do is associate the xml files with their corresponding java files by using appropriate naming conventions.